# Volumes in Docker container on Heroku

Tags: docker, heroku

So I know that the Heroku docs (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime, under "Unsupported Dockerfile commands") lists the VOLUME command as being unsupported as the Heroku file system is ephemeral. Fine. But does that also mean we cannot deploy a Docker container to Heroku that use volumes mapped to external disks somewhere else on Heroku / the internet? If we can use external storage is there a list somewhere of providers I could use?

Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 1):

For Heroku there are only very little kinds of files.

- code, static files: belongs into git
- generated things from the code: are generated when pushing and stored in the dyno
- temporary files: just write locally on the dyno / in the contains
- user-generated media: outside heroku, for example into Amazon S3 (or a similar object-store)